# Can you have Multiple constructor to Parameterize with JUnit/WebDriver

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTestCase {

public String username;
public String password;
public int pin;

    public ParameterizedTestCase(String username,String password, int pin){
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.pin=pin;
}

@Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){

    Object [][] testData = new Object [3][3];

    testData [0][0] = "user1";
    testData [0][1] = "user1pass";
    testData [0][2] = 2345;

    testData [1][0] = "user2";
    testData [1][1] = "user2pass";
    testData [1][2] = 6789;

    testData [2][0] = "user3";
    testData [2][1] = "user3pass";
    testData [2][2] = 1234;

    return Arrays.asList(testData);
}

}

    @Test
    public void loginTest(){    

    System.out.println("Login Test -- " + username + " -- " + password + " 
             --   " + pin);

    }
```

The above code works fine to parameterize in JUnit4.

I would like to add another constructor and `getData()` method for another set of data to parameterize in the same class.

For example:

```
public ParameterizedTestCase(String city,String month, String Day, String year)
```

and `public static Collection<Object[]> getData()`

Can you have multiple constructor in Junit4 to parameterize test data?

I know that Java allows multiple constructor as long as the constructor parameters form a unique signature

I tried but was not successful.

Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible. But if it's not a problem, you could try the [JUnitParams framework](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/) which seems to be what you want. There's a short description of both concepts [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/parameterized-junit-tests-with-junitparams.html), and below is a summary of what you need, taken from the project's doc:

1) dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
  <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2) `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)`

3) Test code config

**short version**

```
@Test
@Parameters({ 
        "17, false", 
        "22, true" })
public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
}
```

**long/complex version**

```
@Test
@Parameters(method = "adultValues")
public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
    assertEquals(valid, new Person(age).isAdult());
}

private Object[] adultValues() {
    return $(
                 $(13, false),
                 $(17, false),
                 $(18, true),
                 $(22, true)
            );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using TestNG to parameterize for now with @DataProvider.